# Symfony validation wrong type invalid value

Tags: php, symfony, validation

I have an entity with the following property and Type validation but i always get a wrong type error `validation.wrong_type`, when i debug it says invalid value it seems that the Space isnt denormalized maybe?

```
/**
 * @var Space|null
 * @Assert\Valid(groups={"Default"})
 * @Assert\Type(Space::class, message=Message::VALIDATION_MESSAGE_WRONG_TYPE, groups={"Default"})
 */
public $space;
```

This is what my Space entity looks like:

```
final class Space
{
    /**
     * @var float|null
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message=Message::VALIDATION_MESSAGE_NOT_BLANK, groups={"Default","Partial"})
     * @Assert\Type(type="float", message=Message::VALIDATION_MESSAGE_WRONG_TYPE, groups={"Default","Partial"})
     */
    public $value;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message=Message::VALIDATION_MESSAGE_NOT_BLANK, groups={"Default","Partial"})
     * @Assert\Type(type="string", message=Message::VALIDATION_MESSAGE_WRONG_TYPE, groups={"Default","Partial"})
     */
    public $unit;
}
```

This is how I pass it in my request:

```
"space": {
  "value": 54.47,
  "unit": "m²"
},
```

What am I doing wrong here

Comment: Have you tried removing the Unicode character (²) from the unit, so just "m" as an experiment, does that still throw an error?...

Comment: @Bossman yes i've tried that, that's not the issue

Comment: Okay, just a thought in case the unicoding was an issue. Can you edit and post the exact error you're getting..

Comment: @Bossman i posted the exact error `validation.wrong_type`

Comment: Hmm okay, from what you have posted i can't tell from the 3 type validations which one it is. Try posting on the [Reddit Group](https://www.reddit.com/r/symfony/), you might get more help there..

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full `Form` configuration you're using to submit the data. Also couldn't help but notice that the Doctrine `ORM` association annotation is missing from the `$space` property, please also update your question to include the Doctrine mapping configuration between the two entities.

Comment: I can see two possibilities: 1. database `float` actually [maps to `double`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.4/reference/basic-mapping.html#doctrine-mapping-types), so change the type in the constraint. As stated in the docs, your locale _might_ not be compatible. 2. For loss of precision reasons, the typehints on the entity could be `string`, check yours. In that case try `numeric` as the `type` or use the [`NumberType`constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/number.html#input).